# label displaying anything

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wmi

I have the code below that uses WMI to get local disk information (got it from another site that I am learning from). Anyway, I created all the labels and combi box and the combi works fine - it displays the local disk on the computer.

However, when I try and get anything back from WMI for the disk selected it and display it then it shows nothing next to the label. WMI works fine as I can use powershell to display get-wmiobjects and the two objects I am bringing back do actually show something through powershell....just not on this application.

Any ideas?

```
namespace diskdrive_info
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get all the disk drives
            ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisk = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
            // Loop through each object (disk) retrieved by WMI
            foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisk.Get())
            {
                cmbHdd.Items.Add(moDisk["Model"].ToString());
            }
        }

        private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + cmbHdd.SelectedItem + "'");
            foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
            {
                lblType.Text = "Type:" + moDisk["MediaType"].ToString();
                lblModel.Text = "Model: " + moDisk["Model"].ToString();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How many times does that foreach run? It looks like you would just be writing over the .Text property however many times as there are elements in the mosDisks.Get() collection. Is there a possibility that the last time the .Get() runs in that loop it's blank or null?

Is "Type:" and "Model:" being shown in the label?

Also try putting in breakpoint in the foreach to watch what comes back for

```
    moDisk["MediaType"].ToString()
```

Comment: Hi - I put a breakpoint in (at the MediaType) bit and I did a step through (F11) and the program stops at the end of Form1_Load. It does not even look at cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged...the first foreach in Form1_Load went through twice and then displayed the winform.

Comment: Do you know what cmbHdd.SelectedItem was when the breakpoint hit? Also, when you add something to the combo, your selectedIndexChanged event could be firing.

Comment: sorry - the debugger does not even hit "private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)" - it ends before that. Probably me and the cr@p debugging skills I have but to me it seems like the program does not even get to the cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged which has the cmbHdd.SelectedItem you mention....can't see why it is not hitting the rest of the code..

Comment: Ok, well since your breakpoint is inside the foreach, try putting it `ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + cmbHdd.SelectedItem + "'");` That should tell you if it's getting in there at all. There is a possibility that the collection it's trying to loop through is empty so the precondition of the foreach is false so it never drops in. After the form loads does the event fire when you actually change the combo?

Comment: for crying out loud...figured it out! It was the fact I was running the script from a network drive and I noticed that when I loaded the script VS errored out saying there is a security risk on running it from this location....so I moved it to C: drive and hey-presto all is fine! I take it VS it is not good running scripts from network drives then...any idea how I can change this so it can trust the network location?

Comment: Well congratulations! Your other question is outside my 'expertise' though sorry!

Answer (score 0):

for crying out loud...figured it out! It was the fact I was running the script from a network drive and I noticed that when I loaded the script VS errored out saying there is a security risk on running it from this location....so I moved it to C: drive and hey-presto all is fine!